# How to set default android:textColorLink

Tags: android, xml, textview, textcolor

I am attempting to set an app-wide style for my TextViews that has a specific color for links. If I set `android:textColorLink` on each individual TextView, it works fine. However, if I set `android:textColorLink` inside a style in `styles.xml`, it continues displaying the normal `android:textColor`. Has anyone else experienced this or know of a solution? I would prefer to set it as the style so I do not need to update multiple references if the color were to change in the future.

---

The following method of individually setting `android:textColorLink` for each TextView **does work** and will display `color1` for normal text and `color2` for links.

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="textStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
</style>
```

Layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="@style/textStyle"
    android:textColorLink="@color/color2" />
```

---

If I instead try just updating the style to include `android:textColorLink` instead of listing it on each TextView, it **does not work** and will display `color1` for all normal text and links.

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="textStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/color2</item>
</style>
```

Layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="@style/textStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A coworker helped me find the solution to this soon after posting. I had assumed that `android:textColorLink` would be able to be set through `android:textAppearance` since I am already setting `android:textColor` the same way. However, it would appear that `android:textColorLink` can only be set through `style`. I am not certain why there is this difference in the ways the colors are applied through styles. If anyone more knowledgeable knows why, please let me know.

---

For example, this works.

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="textStyle1" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
</style>
<style name="textStyle2" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/color2</item>
</style>
```

Layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="@style/textStyle1"
    style="@style/textStyle2" />
```

---

This can also be cleaned up a bit so you only need to set `style` on the TextViews.

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="textStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/color2</item>
</style>
```

Layout file:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/textStyle" />
```